# I do not see readonly Dependency Properties in my XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, dependencies, properties, readonly

I have a custom control with that test-code. Then I put my control on a panel and see it int he preview designer. Then I go where the control is defined in xaml and start typing IsMouseOver... but I can not find this Dep. Property, WHY ? I do not want to offer a SETTTER but I want to offer to the user of my control to bind to the control with a GETTER.

What do I wrong?

```
// Register the private key to set the value
private static readonly DependencyPropertyKey IsMouseOverTestPropertyKey =
              DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly("IsMouseOverTest",
              typeof(bool), typeof(ElementTextBox),
              new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false));

// Register the public property to get the value
public static readonly DependencyProperty IsMouseOverTestProperty =
              IsMouseOverTestPropertyKey.DependencyProperty;

// .NET Property wrapper
public bool IsMouseOverTest
{
    get { return (bool)GetValue(IsMouseOverTestProperty); }
    private set { SetValue(IsMouseOverTestPropertyKey, value); }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you saying is that you don't want users to be able to set this property, e.g. like this:

```
<ElementTextBox IsMouseOverTest="true" .../>
```

And as I understood this is exactly what you are getting... You don't see this property in the intellisense because you cannot set this property.

But you want users to be able to bind to your property using getter, e.g. like this:

```
<ElementTextBox x:Name="MyTextBox" />
<Popup IsOpen="{Binding ElementName=MyTextBox, Path=IsMouseOverTest}"/>
```

If this is what you want, then I don't see the problem. You can do that.

I only can see the problem if you want something like this:

```
<ElementTextBox IsMouseOverTest="{Binding SomeBooleanProperty}" .../>
```

And this will not work, because for that the setter is required.

You might want to set this binding using OneWayToSource mode, like this:

```
<ElementTextBox IsMouseOverTest="{Binding SomeBooleanProperty, Mode=OneWayToSource}" .../>
```

But still it will not work, even though logically it should. This is a known limitation. See https://connect.microsoft.com/WPF/feedback/details/523865/read-only-dependency-properties-does-not-support-onewaytosource-bindings?wa=wsignin1.0

Comment: Use case: User presses an OK button, then in my bound ViewModel I get the bound value from SomeBooleanProperty. Damn why is that not possible? When I offer a SETTER to my user he can SET things which should NOT be there...

Comment: Intellisense does exactly what you expect - it doesn't let you SET the property (setting binding on a property is also SETTING the property). Another thing is that by declaring a dependency property you are automatically allowing to set it. Getter and setter are only there for convenience. Users can set your dependency property this way: MyTextBox.SetValue(MyTextBox.IsMouseOverTestProperty, true).

Comment: I am confused now... to make it simple and short: Lets assume I have the setter declared for my DP. How can I delete/clear all values which could be set using this SETTER ? So the user does not break my algo/logic ?

Comment: Well, you can declare an empty setter that does nothing. Or you can throw an exception in the setter that says the property is read-only and you are not allowed to set it. But, honestly, I don't see a point...

Comment: @Pavlo - You cannot set a correctly declared readonly DP using SetValue from outside the owner control. As declared in the sample code, the Key, which is required for the SetValue call when using RegisterReadOnly, is private. Your sample SetValue will throw an exception.

Comment: @John - Yes, you are right. Didn't notice the read-only declaration.

Comment: @Pavlo If I declare an empty SETTER I can not run the project because Visual Studio hangs up and get this:'IsMouseOverTest' property cannot be data-bound.
Parameter name: dp
   at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.CreateBindingExpression(DependencyObject d, DependencyProperty dp, Binding binding, BindingExpressionBase parent)
   at System.Windows.Data.Binding.CreateBindingExpressionOverride(DependencyObject target, DependencyProperty dp, BindingExpressionBase owner)

Comment: @Pavlo Even when it is read-only and I have that Setter, I can not do:<ElementTextBox IsMouseOverTest="{Binding SomeBooleanProperty}" .../>

Comment: You cannot do that because your property is READONLY. Your are not allowed to set a read-only property and by doing this: IsMouseOverTest="{Binding SomeBooleanProperty}" you are trying to set it!

Comment: @Pavlo ok When I use a DP with .Register(..) and an empty Setter it works... WHEN I put this in the SETTER: throw new Exception("An attempt ot modify Read-Only property"); then I run the project, see my xaml file at top and Visual Studio hangs up, have to close/restart it. WhY this?

Comment: @Pavlo you said:"You cannot do that because your property is READONLY. Your are not allowed to set a read-only property and by doing this: IsMouseOverTest="{Binding SomeBooleanProperty}" you are trying to set it! " but what would be if I use Mode=OnewayToSource which is a readonly action? Should that not work? Why does Binding mean GET and SET the same time?

Comment: Yeah, logically it should work, but currently it is not supported. This is a known limitation. See https://connect.microsoft.com/WPF/feedback/details/523865/read-only-dependency-properties-does-not-support-onewaytosource-bindings?wa=wsignin1.0

Comment: As for throwing an exception in the setter and Visual Studio handing up, I think that's because when it tries to set binding on that property the exception is being raised and visual studio goes to an infinite loop or something...

Answer (score 0):

Did you rebuild the solution? Sometimes the IDE keeps a previous version in cache.

Also :in the xaml where the control is declared all you can do is SET the property and because you did not add a setter this is impossible. Try binding to it in an other control declaration.